# Same type exception from different places

Tags: c#, exception

Let's say you have two different libraries that you write for different format of files. One parses type A of file and one parses type B. Now I see that in most cases most folks say that the exceptions already defined (let's say we use C# and .NET) are enough to handle most situations. In this case I think that is OK that in both cases we if we encounter some problems when parsing we throw a InvalidDataException that tells us that the format is not correct.What happens when we must catch both exceptions in a higher level function that must do something with them?

```
void SomeHigherFunction()
{
    try
    {
        int x = GetSomeDataFromFileA();  // throws InvalidDataException
        int y = GetSomeDataFromFileB();  // throws InvalidDataException
    }
    catch(InvalidDataException)   // what failed ? 
    {
         ShowMessageWithWhatFileFailed()  // what display ?
    }
}
```

How do we know where the code failed? Should in this case be two different Exception types defined, one TypeAException and one TypeBException or is something easy here that I miss? I don't want to wrap each function and return a bool with the result. In this case I would wrap function A in a function and let it return true if successful and execute B further. But that is clearly a bad design and wrong use of exceptions. Should I just create new types in this cases ? Or how?

Comment: Two separate `try/catch` blocks.

Comment: Alternatively, just make the "ShowMessage" rely only on information that is available to an `InvalidDataException` (like using something within the exception `Message`).  Then it won't matter which one failed since you treat them the same way.

Comment: Are you trying to still run both even if the previous one has failed? If so then you need to wrap each in a try catch as @Blorgbeard stated.

Comment: As previously stated, you need **two** `try-catch` blocks in my suspicion. Each should handle details *specific* to that method failing. The purpose of wrapping something in a `try-catch` block is **not** to hide errors, but instead to prevent the processing of instructions that rely on data that has **not** been properly operated on, but is **not** necessary to complete the `method`.

Comment: @jfin3204 No, if the one fails then the other must not execute, that's why I said about wrapping and returning a bool(bad idea - if A(no exception rises) is successful execute B).

Comment: @EBrown Let's say x and y are part of a struct(or class) which will be used further, in this case the execution must be stopped. My question tends to be more whether this is a good candidate for custom exception class or some other solution ...

Comment: Then in that case what is the issue? Your `InvalidDataException` should have the necessary bits of the exception in them (I.e. *stack trace*, *filename that failed*, etc.); if they don't, it's a bad design.

Comment: @EBrown Well, that was more the idea (the question was somehow incomplete), is it OK to use the messages that the exception carries as identifier for the exception itself? This kind of messages can change over time ... also the most important identifier should be the type itself and not the message (which is in my opinion for the programmer). Correct me please if I am wrong ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Exception.Data Collection to pass the owner of the Exception and do something with it further.

I refactored your example a little, but i think this fits your requirements:

```
class Program
{
    [Serializable]
    public abstract class Parser
    {
        public int GetData()
        {
            bool error = true;
            if (error)
            {
                InvalidDataException exception = new InvalidDataException();
                exception.Data.Add("owner", this);
                throw exception;
            }
            return 0;
        }

        public abstract void handleError();
    }
    [Serializable]
    private class ParserA : Parser
    {
        public override void handleError()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Handled in A");
        }
    }
    [Serializable]
    private class ParserB : Parser
    {
        public override void handleError()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Handled in B");
        }
    }
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            int x = new ParserA().GetData();
            int y = new ParserB().GetData();
        }
        catch (InvalidDataException ex)
        {
            Parser parser = ex.Data["owner"] as Parser;
            if(parser != null)
                parser.handleError();

            // or even this if you prefer:
            if (parser is ParserA)
                Console.WriteLine("A");
        }
    }
}
```

In a real case scenario GetData method would be virtual, but you got the idea

Comment: Well, the problem is that "A failed" and "B failed" is a message for the programmer and not for the user and you need to identify somehow which one failed and format it for the user. Or better imagine that you must take different actions, log it if A failed, load another file if B failed. Both cases are actually identical.

Comment: The message is for the user, and its already formatted. If you want to have specific logic for each error, it should be done before throwing on the specific methods, not when catching, which may lead to an awful code to maintain.

Comment: I don't know if exception messages(even at high level) should be already formatted for the user, they might change to something more specific for one of the functions and then you must again identify which is which. As for handling before throwing might be tricky because you can have two different libraries that are independently developed and none of it cares who calls it(that's why the conflict).

Comment: Ok, i will edit with something that may suit your need, please tell me what you think

Comment: If your idea was to change the two libraries so they inherit from the same base class and they should handle the error cases then that's not what I wanted because the libraries are not related. But if your intent was to wrap each function inside the new Parser (the name is the problem, it's more like ParserHandler or something) class then this is what I wanted and it's very nicely done(It's as OOP as it can be done). And even if you still rely on strings (what I don't necessarily like)  to identify the correct parser you gave me a elegant idea! Thanks...

Comment: The inheritance was just for simplicity, the main point was to use the Data collection for type safety. I'm glad I could help you somehow, Cheers